# Vue-cli build and publish to my server show multiple error log in console

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli

I build a website by vue-cli2. It can work in my localhost, but when I run build and upload to my server it log error (figure1) in console. How could I fix it

[figure1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/urBk0.png)

Comment: Probably because you are using a subdirectory?  like `example.com/subdir/index.html`  but your app looks for the files at the root `example.com/app.795123.js`  There is a publicPath config setting, or probably baseURL if you are using an older version https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#baseurl